# NSSearchfield's content misaligned

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nssearchfield

Since upgrading to 10.9 Mavericks, I noticed that the content of all `NSSearchfield` instances are misaligned: both the magnifying glass icon, the textfield itself and the clear button are moved down a little bit.

Any idea what could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily could fix it by subclassing `NSSearchField` and choosing a custom class as cell class:

```
+ (void) load {
    [super load];
    [self setCellClass:[RMSearchFieldCell class]];
}
```

The `RMSearchFieldCell` moves the origin of the cells +1 by overwriting the `searchTextRectForBounds:`, `searchButtonRectForBounds:` and `cancelButtonRectForBounds:` methods:

```
- (NSRect) cancelButtonRectForBounds:(NSRect)rect {
    NSRect superRect = [super cancelButtonRectForBounds:rect];
    superRect.origin.y -=1;
    return superRect;
}
```

However this is not the elegant way of doing it, and I'm still looking for the reason for the misalignment.